# Eclipse workspace config extract

Tags: java, eclipse, upgrade

Every time, almost, Eclipse upgrades by a minor revision (e.g. 4.5 to 4.6), the workspace format changes.

Your 4.6 IDE could still open a 4.5 generated workspace, but soon certain misbehaviours or missing behaviours would start showing up or not showing.

Then the advice Eclipse gurunaths would give us is - start with a new workspace.

OK.

Is there a way to produce an extract of all the config of an Eclipse workspace, that could be imported into a new workspace, so that I don't have to go thro tediously replicating the feature-config of the old workspace into the new workspace?

So far, I only know you could extract code templates, coding styles or maven launches. But there are tons of other preferences. And why not in one single extract file too.

Comment: "[...] but soon certain misbehaviours or missing behaviours would start showing up or not showing." => I never encountered such problems. Installing and starting a newer Eclpise version with pointing it to an _existing_ workspace of an older version, works very fine. Eclipse recognizes the older format of the workspace and updates it, too! Besides that, you always can do File -> Export -> General -> Preferences -> (tick all). This will export many thing at once.

Comment: Your question is probably going to be closed as too broad, or opinion based. However this is a very good question for the eclipse team. Maybe go to the eclipse.org website and see if they have a feedback mechanism, and make the suggestion there (They do have an export preferences option, but it only seems to export some of the preferences)

Comment: Unless you have very complex projects like mine, you wouldn't see the misbehaviours. Perhaps you don't use maven, or Spring. Asking if there is a way to produce and extract is "opinion based"?

Comment: If you encounter bugs, there is nothing SO can do for you, you have to tell them to the Eclipse team. And you have to be much more specific (or precise).

Comment: I had been an active participant of eclipse bugzilla. But I am required to verify if there is already a solution before submitting a bug report. I guess that might already be a bug/request, because this issue has been rousing complaints for quite some time.

Comment: I am not asking for a solution to bugs. I am asking if there is an extract.

Comment: "Eclipse recognizes the older format of the workspace and updates it, too". In theory, there is no difference between in theory and in practice. But in practice, there is. Baseball anyone?

Comment: "File -> Export -> General -> Preferences -> (tick all). This will export many thing at once" ? Does it export "show line numbers"? installed JRE/JDK paths? AWS? Google? Maven? Spring? Text Editor Settings? XML preferences?